# How can I plot two smoothing splines in the same plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example, I have a couple of plots like this:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = T)
```

Is it possible to plot 2 of these kind into the same plot?

Comment: look for `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, but try making facets, it will give you more scaled plot with single legend

Comment: I want to have the functions plotted in the same coordinate system, not two plots on one page.

Comment: If you only want to add another fonction, add another layer: `+ geom_smooth()`


e.g.: `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = T) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 4), se = T)`

Comment: @bVa This is I want, but would it be possible that the other layer is from a different data frame?

Comment: It is possible: add it inside `geom_smooth`.

`+ geom_smooth(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cyl), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 4), se = T)`

Comment: @bVa Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. Only one question: how can I add different colours and a legend?

Comment: If you want a legend, according to the color, put `color` inside the aes.

`ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(aes(color = "B"),method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = T) + geom_smooth(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cyl, color = "A"), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 4), se = T) + scale_color_manual("Legend Title", values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to add another fonction, add another layer: `+ geom_smooth()`

[image: Plot 1]

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = T) +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 4), se = T)
```

---

If you want to add data from a different data frame, add `df` information inside `geom_smooth` :

[image: plot 2]

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = T) + 
geom_smooth(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cyl), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 4), se = T)
```

---

Finally, customize colors and legend : 
`color` argument needs to be inside `aes` to appear in the legend

[image]

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(aes(color = "B"),method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = T) + 
geom_smooth(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cyl, color = "A"), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 4), se = T) + 
scale_color_manual("Legend Title", values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue"))
```